# Allowing some application to access my Gallery

Tags: applications

While allowing some android applications to access my gallery, am i allow them also view all my pictures, downloads etc?

Or are they only be able to pick an image for example when i use an image through that application?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "allowing some android applications to access my gallery"? What actually happens on the screen:

Comment: @DanHulme thanks for attention. I mean, when i decided to install an app from Google Play, it asks if i allow the app to reach my gallery, and some other places. I wonder if these apps can read all my pics etc